# No aparece namespace, using y tampoco la funcion main

Tags: c#

yo anteriormente usaba sharpdevelop y en ese me aparecia el namespace, el using systemy la funcion main, pero ahora cuando me pase en visual estudio todo eso no se me genera automaticamente, al ver videos de youtube vi que si es posible se le genera todo correctamente pero ami no, que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna captura?, ¿que tipo de proyecto has escogido de c#?, ¿qué versión usas?. Tal como está solo se te puede desear lo mejor, ya que con tan poca información a no ser que te haya pasado exactamente lo mismo es imposible de identificar. Fijate en que usa el del video y si usa net framework o el normal ya que se generan diferente

Comment: Seria bueno ver tu codigo, o colocas aqui un proyecto que hayas generado asi o lo colocas en algun repositorio publico (por ejemplo Github) asi te podremos ayudar mejor y con el codigo que generaste. Pero asi como comentas con las ["instrucciones de nivel superior (top level templates)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) que te comentam que viene por default, pero puedes no utilizarlos. Dale una mirada al enlace.

Answer (score 2):

Es una característica que existe desde .Net 6, la cual te permite crear proyectos con código "simplificado" y reducido. (en lo personal no me gusta)

Más información [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

Cuando creas un proyecto, eventualmente llegas a esta pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Con el Check marcado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Sin el Check

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bien "simplifica", es cierto que los que estamos acostumbrados al "ver todos los using que se utilizan en un archivo" las deshabilitamos. Para eso hay que seguir esto [Deshabilitación de directivas using implícitas](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#disable-implicit-using-directives)